# What is the benefit of using java.util.properties while connecting to database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I was reading [Oreilly Java Programming With Oracle JDBC edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000882.do) and I notice that there was one example using java.util.properties object like below;

```
public class Connector {


    Connection con = null;
    private Properties info = new Properties();

    public void connect(){
        info.put("user", "sys as sysdba");
        info.put("password", "testpass");
        String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String serverName = "localhost";
        String port = "1521";
        String sid = "XE";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + port + ":" + sid;



        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void closeConnection(){

        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I have checked API that I understand main benefit of properties is reading local sources. Google OCI driver examples using java.util.properties more than thin driver examples. My question is;

*Should I use properties for thin driver?
*if yes what will be benefit?

*Why I can not cast full details as properties that I have to use String object for connection?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The properties *could* be loaded from some `jdbc.properties` file on classpath which allows you for external configuration. Its sole content could look like:

```
user=sys as sysdba
password=testpass
```

So, instead of

```
info.put("user", "sys as sysdba");
info.put("password", "testpass");
```

you *could* do

```
info.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jdbc.properties"));
```

*(note that the filename is free to your choice, it'll work as long as it's in the runtime classpath)*

This way you don't need to edit, recompile, rebuild, fuss the class whenever you want to change the connection details. You just have to edit a simple textbased file. This is particularly helpful in distributed applications which needs to be managed by someone without any Java knowledge (e.g. serveradmins).

#### See also:

- [Java Properties tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I use as well for thin drivers?

Comment: I really don't see why they would need special treatment. Oh, I would add that you could also put servername, port, sid, etc in such a properties file and obtain it by `info.getProperty("servername")` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

"To log on as SYSDBA with the JDBC Thin driver you must configure the server to use the password file. "
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/dbmgmnt.htm

I'm trying to use a thin driver to connect to Oracle as sysdba but the connections are failing.  I tried steps there but my attempts after those changes also fail.

Anyone interested in this, may also be interested in the internal_logon property since it is mentioned in relation to logging on for specific roles like sysdba but again, I had no success using that either.